# Hand Gestures with Kinect

Tags: kinect, gesture, raspberry-pi3, simple-openni, nite

I am trying to make Hand Gestures like grabbing and Dragging, for example Windows on my Desktop, using the Kinect Camera, which I connected to a Raspberry Pi running with Raspbian. I already installed OpenNI+Nite, freenect and the PrimeSense driver.

So how do I start? Because I'm rather new to this, I would appreciate it if somebody could give an example or a general idea of how something like this could be done.

Comment: What exactly do you want for the first step? The question is too broad